# ubuntu 20.04 hanging on login

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, lubuntu

so - was on lubuntu 18 two days ago - was working fine.  Upgraded to 20.04 - upgrade went fine, no errors or anything boots up perfectly.

- if I try to login with a bad password, i get bad password errror
- if I i hit control-alt-F3/f4 whatever, before I login, I get a tty, where I can happily login to the text version
- If I try to login with correct credentials - the machine seems to hang - which means:

  - nothing on the screen responds
  - control-alt-F? does something - just taking me to an empty screen with a cursor
  - from my wifi router, the machine appears to have dropped off the network

I have googled and found a number of things about nvidia drivers, but I'm running this on an old macbook, so I don't think it's nvidia.

Comment: The Lubuntu 20.04 release notes (https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/) state "*due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install*" so issues should have been expected. I'd check you have space in $HOME  (and note Lubuntu is a desktop, all desktop releases are *yy.mm* in format, there is *snap* only Lubuntu 18; *yy* releases being *snap* only since 2016)

Comment: I found the problem - but I don't know what the problem is - if that makes any sense...  I have an rc.local which starts expressvpn, does a mount -a, and starts the vnc server.  All of those run fine _after_ I log in, but one of them, (and so far haven't done the effort to work out which), if run before I login causes the login to basically completely stop the machine working.

Comment: Don't know if it's of help, but https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/G/AdvancedNetworking.html  (VPN reference in the Lubuntu manual)